# What is the Optimized Way to Dynamic SQL Select all Columns from Table?

Tags: sql-server, performance, dynamic-sql, performance-tuning

I just generated this script.
It will select all columns from a table dynamically.

Is there an alternative or more clean, efficient way of conducting this?
Additionally, I want to place line breaks for each column; char(10) and char(13) are not working.

```
declare @Tablename nvarchar(max) = 'dbo.customer'

DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX) =
'SELECT ' + STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + char(10) + char(13) + QUOTENAME(c.name) 
    FROM sys.columns c where c.object_id = object_id(@Tablename)
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') +
 ' FROM ' + @Tablename
;

select @qry
```

**Current Result**

```
SELECT [customerid], [customernamename] FROM dbo.customer
```

**Intended Result:**

```
SELECT 
[customerid], 
[customernamename] 
FROM dbo.customer
```

Comment: When you ask about an optimized way - is the query you have running slowly?

Comment: perhaps, I plan to run this query for all tables in all databases, over multiple servers, if not optimized ,  just wondering if there is better way to simplify the syntax at least,

Comment: If you really want **all** columns, then why not simply use `select *  from ...`? Also: there is not functional or performance difference between the current result and the intended result.

Comment: was taught to refrain from using *, we want to list the columns for this -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a more *efficient* way of retrieving the list of columns, but I will address the issue of line breaks using the following example (I reversed your char(10) + char(13) to be char(13) + char(10).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Customers;
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [CustomerID] [int] NULL,
    [CustomerName] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

declare @Tablename nvarchar(max) = 'dbo.customers'

DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX) =
'SELECT ' + STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + char(13) + char(10) + QUOTENAME(c.name) 
    FROM sys.columns c where c.object_id = object_id(@Tablename)
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') +
  + char(13) + char(10) + 'FROM ' + @Tablename
;

select @qry
```

---

```
SELECT 
[CustomerID], 
[CustomerName]
FROM dbo.customers
```

---

You can either change your SSMS output to go to text or, if you prefer grid view, make sure you do the following:

1. Tools > Options
2. Expand Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid
3. Tick Retain CR/LF on copy or save
4. **Restart SSMS**